# how to call a variable using awk in a for loop?

Tags: variables, for-loop, awk

I am uncertain on how to correctly all a variable in a for loop. I have currently set a variable equal to the total number of lines in a file and want to use it in a for loop that will run a set of code.

I tried the following:

```
variable=$(awk 'END { print NR }' file)
```

I want to use this variable in a for loop, here is a simple example:

```
for i in {1..$variable}; do

     print ${i}

done
```

This doesn't work as I think I have called the `variable` incorrectly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `{n..m}` cannot use variables because the brace expansion is performed before the variables are evaluated. So to do this you need to use `seq`.